# Merge tags for variable-length arguments

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

We have several different tags which are used in the context of passing an unspecified number of arguments to a function or method:

- [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/varargs) × 537
  *Wiki Summary:* Variadic functions are functions which accept a variable numbers of arguments.
  Also has a good tag-wiki.
- [variadic-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-functions) × 304
  *Wiki Summary:* functions that accept varying numbers of arguments -- for example, the function may be called with 1 argument or 2 arguments.
- [variadic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic) × 194
  *Wiki Summary:* In computer science, an operator or function is variadic if it can take a varying number of arguments; that is, if its arity is not fixed.
- [variableargumentlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variableargumentlists) × 88
  *No wiki*
- [variable-length-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-length-arguments) × 42
  *No wiki*
- [variadic-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-parameter) × 10
  *Wiki Summary:* A parameter, operator or function is classed as variadic if it can taking a variable number of arguments.

Can we re-tag and merge these tags, or mark them as duplicates?

Also related: [variadic-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-templates) (× 868), [variadic-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-macro) (× 71) and [polyvariadic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polyvariadic) (× 16) cover subsets of the general theme. So they are not synonyms in the strict sense, and therefore not covered by this request here.
Sometimes [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters) (x 525 + [optional-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-arguments) x 75) is more appropriate though.

Comment: I just came across varargs/variadic-functions myself. I think this could do with being shuffled along from discussion to taking concrete action.

Answer (score 4):

*I'm writing two proposals, which are not mutually exclusive. Please vote as you see fit.*

**Keep [variadic-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-functions)**

We could merge the listed ones into that. In this setup, we'd *distinguish* things that tag from the ones for templates and macros. In languages where such a distinction is moot users might be confused. The name “variadic functions” matches the title of [the corresponding Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), which might help consistency.

If we also keep [variadic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic), then that would be a common supertag for functions, templates and macros.

Answer (score 3):

This is now partially completed.

**I merged the [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/varargs) tag into the [variadic-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-functions) tag** and created a synonym mapping, essentially doing what was recommended [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277486/366904).

That effectively gives us the best of both worlds: the master tag is a more descriptive one, but for programmers that know it by the term "varargs", they can type "varargs" into any textbox on the site and it will be automatically remapped to "variadic-functions". Thus, no one has to actually search for "variadic-functions".

**Same thing with [variadic-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-parameter), [variable-length-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-length-arguments), [variableargumentlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variableargumentlists), [va-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/va-list), and [va-arg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/va-arg)**. Looking carefully at the questions with these tags, they were not used in a manner distinct from [variadic-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-functions), so merging was appropriate. There is no need to have separate tags for [va-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/va-list) and [va-arg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/va-arg). If your question is about either of those things, you have a variadic function. This fixed all of the questions with *only* [va-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/va-list) *or* [va-arg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/va-arg), which were easily lost.

I also manually merged in the tag wiki information from [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/varargs) into [variadic-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-functions), so the tag has an acceptable wiki now.

---

**I did *not* touch the [variadic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic) tag**. An automatic merge is not appropriate here; **it needs to be manually cleaned up** in order to allow a human brain to disambiguate between [variadic-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-macros) and [variadic-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-templates). (No, I don't think all of these should be made synonymous with [variadic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic).)

Answer (score -1):

**Keep [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/varargs)**

As this [Google Trends comparison](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=varargs%2C%20varargs%20-c%20-cpp%2C%20%22variadic%20functions%22&cmpt=q) demonstrates, it is a rather commonly used term, even outside C or C++ circles.

Note that this applies mainly to functions (methods). [variadic-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-functions) can be a synonym for users who search by the technical term. This seems to be quite rare, as per the search trends linked above.

Answer (score -2):

Merge them all into one (new) [variable-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-arguments)

(and give this an additional synonym [variable-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-parameters)?)

Comment: I just found another tag (varargs) with a much larger number of questions.

Comment: Indeed time for a cleanup then ;-) I still propose 'variable-arguments' which is easier to understand (less 'techie')

Comment: I for one wouldn't understand `variable-arguments`, and wouldn't search for it either. The full term is “variable *number* of arguments”. The arguments themselves are not neccessarily variable. If that `variable-arguments` tag would already exist, I'd suggest keeping it as a synonym, but since it's absent so far I guess the existing tags are easy enough to find - or at least one of them. As the canonical form I'd prefer a technical and therefore exact term.

Answer (score -2):

*I'm writing two proposals, which are not mutually exclusive. Please vote as you see fit.*

**Keep [variadic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic)**

We could merge all the listed tags into that, and also add that tag to questions tagged [variadic-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-templates) or similar. “Variadic” the appropriate technical term here, and covers all situations, *including* variadic templates and macros.

If we also keep [variadic-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-functions) then that could be used to distinguish functions from templates while keeping the more general tag for common issues.

The most-often-used tag name [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/varargs) is common for C programmers, but might be too language-specific, so I'd avoid that, and instead use some longer, more descriptive and less implementation- and language-specific term.

Comment: Best keep [tag:varargs] instead. It's short and sweet, and not nearly as restricted to C and C++ as you think. 388 of 533 questions are neither tagged C nor C++.

Comment: @Deduplicator I've added that as an answer so people can vote on it.